# Passing a map with struct-type key into a Spark UDF

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to write an Spark 1.6 UDF which takes the following map:

```
case class MyRow(mapping: Map[(Int, Int), Double])

val data = Seq(
  MyRow(Map((1, 1) -> 1.0))
)
val df = sc.parallelize(data).toDF()

df.printSchema()

root
 |-- mapping: map (nullable = true)
 |    |-- key: struct
 |    |-- value: double (valueContainsNull = false)
 |    |    |-- _1: integer (nullable = false)
 |    |    |-- _2: integer (nullable = false)
```

(As a side-note: I find the above output strange as the Type of the key is printed below the type of the value, why is that?)

Now I define my UDF as:

```
val myUDF = udf((inputMapping: Map[(Int,Int), Double]) =>
  inputMapping.map { case ((i1, i2), value) => ((i1 + i2), value) }
)

df
  .withColumn("udfResult", myUDF($"mapping"))
  .show()
```

But this gives me:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GenericRowWithSchema cannot be cast to scala.Tuple2
```

So I tried to replace `(Int,Int)` with a custom `case class`, because this is how I normally do it if I want to pass a `struct` to an UDF:

```
case class MyTuple2(i1: Int, i2: Int)
val myUDF = udf((inputMapping: Map[MyTuple2, Double]) => 
  inputMapping.map { case (MyTuple2(i1, i2), value) => ((i1 + i2), value) }
)
```

This strangely gives :

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve 'UDF(mapping)' due to data type mismatch: argument 1 requires map<struct<i1:int,i2:int>,double> type, however, 'mapping' is of map<struct<_1:int,_2:int>,double> type.
```

I don't understand the above exception as the types match.

The only (ugly) solution I've found is passing a `org.apache.spark.sql.Row` and then "extract" the elements of the struct:

```
val myUDF = udf((inputMapping: Map[Row, Double]) => inputMapping
  .map { case (key, value) => ((key.getInt(0), key.getInt(1)), value) } // extract Row into Tuple2
  .map { case ((i1, i2), value) => ((i1 + i2), value) }
)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no escaping the use of `Row` in this context: a tuple (or case class) used within a map (or another tuple/case class/array...) is a *nested* structure, and as such it would be represented as a `Row` when passed into a UDF.

The only improvement I can suggest is using `Row.unapply` to simplify the code a bit:

```
val myUDF = udf((inputMapping: Map[Row, Double]) => inputMapping
  .map { case (Row(i1: Int, i2: Int), value) => (i1 + i2, value) }
)
```